# What is the best Android gaming engine for Billiards game?

Tags: 2d, android, physics

What is the best engine/way to go with when implementing a 2D billiards game? I am thinking about [Emini Physics Engine](http://www.emini.at/), which is free for use and stuff, but maybe you can give me some pitfalls about this engine and recommend some other or encourage me into using this?

Comment: Have a look at this question: [Is there an algorithm for a pool game?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7862/is-there-an-algorithm-for-a-pool-game)

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely recommend researching how to roll your own for this task. It is probably easier than you might think. There is still a lot of complexity there, but it would be a great learning exercise.

I highly recommend reading [Pool Hall Lessons: Fast, Accurate Collision Detection Between Circles or Spheres by Joe van den Heuvel, Miles Jackson](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3015/pool_hall_lessons_fast_accurate_.php).